# How to partition a powerset

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a poset which is the powerset of $\{a, b, c, d\}$ ordered by set inclusion and I know by Dilworth's Theorem that I can partition it into $6$ chains as the cardinality of its largest maximal antichain is $6$. I can't seem to come up with a way to do this, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximal antichain consists of all of the 2-element subsets.

Each of those ends up anchoring a chain. It is easy enough to attach each of the 1-element subsets to a 2-element superset of its own -- for example $\{a\}$ to $\{a,b\}$, $\{b\}$ to $\{b,c\}$, $\{c\}$ to $\{c,d\}$ and $\{d\}$ to $\{d,a\}$. Then attach $\varnothing$ to one of the singletons.

Taking complements, do the same thing for the subsets with $>2$ elements.

Comment: Thank you! A quick question, could you consider $\{ \{a\}, \{b,c\}, \{b,d\}, \{c,d\} \}$ a maximal antichain? I can't seem to find another antichain that is a proper subset of.

Comment: @ao2130: Yes, that's a maximal antichain too. But it's not the _largest_ maximal antichain.